# I am unable to redirect to a HTML page in Node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a couple of API endpoints /auth/register and /auth/login and /auth is base URL and have endpoint on /register and /login.

My folder structure is:

[image]

I am redirecting signup page from app.js and it works:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' })
  return res.redirect('signup.html')
  // res.status(200).send('Yes, working')
})
```

But when I hit the submit button on signup page, it does not reirect to the sign in page. Here is the signup page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Signup</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 main">
                    <form action="/auth/register" method="post">
                        <h1> Signup form </h1>
            <input class="box" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter your First Name"  required /><br>
            <input class="box" type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter your Last Name"  required /><br>
                        <input class="box" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail " required /><br>
                        <input class="box" type="password" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Enter your Password " required/><br>
                        <input class="box" type="text" name="role" id="role"  placeholder="Enter your Role " required/><br>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" id="submitDetails"  name="submitDetails" value="Submit Your Details" /><br>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My /auth/register API

```
router.post('/register, (req, res, next) => {
res.redirect('signin.html')
//also tried ../public/signin.html
//also tried sendFile but it unable to load css file
})
```

So it seems I am committing the mistake related to the path because when I load from the app.js it works but when the /auth/register runs that resides in the auth folder it unable to redirect.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in that last example, please double check that this is an accurate [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```
 return res.redirect('signup.html')

 redirect(url)
```

You redirect the user to a route, therefore you have to pass a url. for example:

```
redirect("/myPage")
```

In order to show this endpoint to the client, you should already have this endpoint defined. But looks like you want to send a html document instead of redirecting the user to a different route. so you should have:

```
 res.sendFile("signup.html")
```

Once you write this code, express will automatically look for the static folder. so you should already have told express the location of publicly available files. then express will go inside the public folder and inside the public folder look for signup.html and send it.

This is how you inform express about static files' location.

```
  app.use(express.static('public'))
```

This means  files that inside "public" folder that in the root directory are publicly available.

Since `express.static` is a middleware function, this has to be placed before the routes. Because in this situation

```
router.get("/myPage",(req,res)=>{
res.sendFile("signup.html")})

   app.use(express.static('public'))
```

when client hits ",myPage" endpoint, since this end point is not aware of the location of public folder, your app will throw an error.

this code that you placed has a different purpose:

```
router.post('/register, (req, res, next) => {
res.redirect('signin.html')
//also tried ../public/signin.html
//also tried sendFile but it unable to load css file
})
```

router.post means send a POST request to "/register". Posting request is when a client sends some data or submit a form to the endpoint. But visiting a website is a GET request. So if you wanna display something to the user, you need to use `router.get()`.